# What is the best Java SIP Stack around?

Tags: java, sip

What is the best Java SIP Stack I can use.

I'm looking for Stable, Efficient, Rich Feature-Set,  Stable & Bug-less :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol

Comment: And http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=moon%20on%20a%20stick

Comment: good question, I hate it when they close questions like this.

Answer (score 4):

[MjSip](http://www.mjsip.org/) - complete, well documented, and Open Source

Comment: where's the documentation for making it work...I agree the API's are documented nicely...but I am not able to run even the example codes.

Answer (score 3):

I hope it is NOT MjSip. I may be wrong but I don't think that the api has been worked on since 2005. I have used it for a month now and it is missing some higher level things like easy dtmf support and has the occasional bug. Although, I think some decent projects like SipDroid for android used it as a basis.

Two other stacks I know of are:

1) PJSIP-JNI which is java bindings for the C PJSIP library

2) JAIN-SIP

Answer (score 0):

This is a good library to start with. The project has a lot of modules, but the SIP and RTP implementations are simple and pure java (including g729 codec !!!)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaforce/

Answer (score -2):

though java is not very much used [here](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/talk_developers_home.html), i hope it's helpful, this is google talk approach